# MultiTouchHandler Few Errors?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multi-touch

Getting a few errors and not sure what to do. Please help. Trying to develop snake game in android version 1.5 and using the eclipse sdk version 4.2.0 seem that these errors are the only thing holding me back from being able to debug my game.

```
The method getX() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getY() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getX() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getY() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getPointerCount() is undefined for the type MotionEvent  
The method getPointerId(int) is undefined for the type MotionEvent  
ACTION_POINTER_DOWN cannot be resolved or is not a field    
The method getX() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getY() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
ACTION_POINTER_UP cannot be resolved or is not a field  MultiTouchHandler.java  
ACTION_MASK cannot be resolved or is not a field    
ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK cannot be resolved or is not a field 
ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT cannot be resolved or is not a field
The method getPointerId(int) is undefined for the type MotionEvent
```

The code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
    synchronized (this) {  
        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;  
        int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >>   MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;  
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);   

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
            touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN;
            touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
            touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getX(pointerIndex) * scaleX);
            touchEvent.y = touchY[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getY(pointerIndex) * scaleY);
            isTouched[pointerId] = true;
            touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
            touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP;
            touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
            touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getX(pointerIndex) * scaleX);
            touchEvent.y = touchY[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getY(pointerIndex) * scaleY);
            isTouched[pointerId] = false;
            touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
                pointerIndex = i;
                pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

                touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
                touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED;
                touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
                touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event
                        .getX(pointerIndex) * scaleX);
                touchEvent.y = touchY[pointerId] = (int) (event
                        .getY(pointerIndex) * scaleY);
                touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
            }
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are try to achive here touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getX(pointerIndex) * scaleX); ???

it shoulb be like this

touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getX() * scaleX);

Comment: i create a pool for TouchEvent instance register the handlers as an OnTouchListener, and store the scrolling values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these mthods that you are getting errors for are not available in your chosen API level. Either increase the API level or remove any multitouch-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods/variables are not matching up to the type required on the context in which you are using them by the looks of it.

Look through your code and see if the method arguments and return types all match up.

Comment: pretty sure they all match up